# Parse query not returning

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to do a little script on Cloud Code that sends an email whenever an object of type `Reservas` is created. This email needs to contain the information about the user that created this object. I know that using a related field would be better, but this option is not possible at the moment.

What I thought of doing is a query using the email from the `Reservas` object and the email property from the user but I can't seem to get to the line `console.log("--> Usuario encontrado")`

Here's what I tried to do:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Reservas", function(request) {
    var assunto = "Reserva App Criada - ";
    var conteudo = "Reserva App CRIADA\n"

    try {
        query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        query.equalTo("email", request.object.get("email"));
        query.find({
            sucess: function(usuario) {
                console.log("--> Usuario encontrado")
                mandarEmail(conteudo, assunto, request, usuario)
            }, error: function(error) {
                console.log("--> Usuario não encontrado")
                emailErro(request, error);
            }
    })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("--> Erro:" + err);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was just a silly typo. I wrote `sucess` instead of `success`